# How does Serilog retrieve key information?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I need a requirement like this, I need to create a log message record of any kind using the logging framework. Then record some logs in some key places, and then I need to retrieve some information from it, how is this done?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oito.png)

Like this, or is there any other framework that is easier to implement? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create a logging using Serilog?

Comment: Image is missing. Can you share some context? What sort of app is it? Where were you thinking the logs should be kept? What do you mean by "retrieve some information from it"? A simple file log will write to a file, and you can then open it with a text viewer or an editor; or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Required Nuget Packages:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="MyLogInfo\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**appsettings.json configuration：**

```
{

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console "
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "MyLogInfo\\MyLogInfo.txt",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then add code in startup.cs to read these Serilog settings in the constructor：

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
       .CreateLogger();
        }
```

Finally change the code in program.cs to specify that Host Builder uses Serilog from ASP.NET Core instead of the default logger：

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

For more details, please refer to this article:

[Implementing logging with Serilog](https://garywoodfine.com/implementing-logging-with-serilog/)

More logging frameworks can read this:

[Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Then you want to read information from this log?

You can read this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh758325(v=win.10)

Comment: I want to retrieve its data, but looking it up directly seems better, thank you.